# Beginner question in XCODE, error: Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arraylist

I am new to XCode and I am following an online tutorial for a shopping list program. I have this error that appears twice, "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts". If anyone is able to help me or give guidance that would be appreciated, thank you!

```
private func seedItems() {
    let ud = UserDefaults.standard
    
    if !ud.bool(forKey: "UserDefaultsSeedItems") {
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "seed", ofType: "plist"), let seedItems = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            // Items
            var items = [Item]()
            
            // Create List of Items
            for seedItem in seedItems {
                if let name = seedItem["name"] as? String, let price = seedItem["price"] as? Float { //this is where the error appears
                    print("\(name) - \(price)")
                    
                    // Create Item
                    let item = Item(name: name, price: price)
                    
                    // Add Item
                    items.append(item)
                }
            }
            
            print(items)
            
            if let itemsPath = pathForItems() {
                // Write to File
                if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, toFile: itemsPath) {
                    ud.set(true, forKey: "UserDefaultsSeedItems")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to type cast seedItem as Dictionary. Currently it is of type Any.

Comment: Thank you, can you please show me how to write this I am still learning

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` is an Objective-C array. The type system knows nothing about the contents of your `NSArray` so it assumes they are of type `Any`.

The quick fix to the problem is to cast each item to its correct type.

```
if let seedItemDict = seedItem as? Dictionary 
{
    if let name = seedItemDict["name"] 
    // etc
}
else 
{
    // Error the items were not dictionaries
}
```

However, I noticed that the initialiser you used is deprecated so you should look for a better way to load your property list.

It turns out you can decode a property list with `Decodable` objects. You should look at using a [PropertyListDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistdecoder).